# R tibble all the coocuring words of the string - coocurences - bigram - dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, nlp

I have a Data Frame of this format:

```
df <- data.frame(names= c('perform data cleansing','information categorisation', ''))
                             names
1           perform data cleansing
2       information categorisation
3 write batch record documentation
```

And I would like to obtain this one with all the coocurences:

```
                             names           tokens1              tokens2
1           perform data cleansing           perform                 data
1           perform data cleansing              data            cleansing 
1           perform data cleansing         cleansing              perform
2       information categorisation       information       categorisation
3 write batch record documentation             write                batch
3 write batch record documentation             write               record
3 write batch record documentation             write        documentation 
3 write batch record documentation             batch               record 
3 write batch record documentation             batch        documentation 
3 write batch record documentation            record        documentation
```

so, for `n` words in a string, you'll have `n x (n-1) / 2` coocurencies.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a few ways to go about it, so it's helpful to know how you want to approach it, such as if you're already using a text mining package

Comment: Hello Camille, if you know a package doing it, I am taking! To be honest, so far I am surprised it does not exist already. What I need by the end is a data frame format (Tibble or other can be good).

Comment: If you're already comfortable in the tidyverse (guessing since you tagged `dplyr`), you might check out [`tidytext`](https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html) as the text mining counterpart to the tidyverse

Answer (score 0):

We could split the 'names' by the space, loop through the `list` splitted elements, get the combination of words picking two at a time an `unnest` the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(tokens = strsplit(names, " ") %>%
                     map(~ .x %>%
                          combn(m = 2, simplify = FALSE))) %>%
   unnest
```

---

If we need as two separate 'tokens' columns, we `paste` the `combn`ination of words together, then `unnest`, and `separate` the 'tokens' into two columns by splitting at the delimiter that was used for `paste`ing together

```
df %>%
    mutate(tokens = strsplit(names, " ") %>%
                      map(~ .x %>%
                           combn(m = 2, FUN = function(x) 
                                paste(x[1], x[2], sep="-"), simplify = FALSE))) %>%
                                    unnest %>%
                                    unnest %>% 
                                    separate(tokens, into = c('tokens1', 'tokens2'))
#                               names     tokens1        tokens2
#1            perform data cleansing     perform           data
#2            perform data cleansing     perform      cleansing
#3            perform data cleansing        data      cleansing
#4        information categorisation information categorisation
#5  write batch record documentation       write          batch
#6  write batch record documentation       write         record
#7  write batch record documentation       write  documentation
#8  write batch record documentation       batch         record
#9  write batch record documentation       batch  documentation
#10 write batch record documentation      record  documentation
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(names = c("perform data cleansing", 
   "information categorisation", 
 "write batch record documentation")), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: I'm getting a couple different errors here: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-character argument.` when running your code as is. If I convert `names` from factor to character, I get `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: n < m.`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @camille  I am pretty sure that you know the reason for the error i.e. `strsplit` takes `character` class arguments and not `factor` class.

Comment: Okay, figured you would want to know that when running your solution with the data as provided by the OP, it errored and couldn't run. It works now when using the data as you posted it, so maybe you could explain to the OP how you adjusted the data to fit your proposed solution

Comment: No, I still got errors after converting to character

Comment: @camille  Sorry, I don't know how you are converting to `character`

Comment: Using the OP's data and adding `mutate(names = as.character(names))` before your `mutate` call yields `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: n < m.` But if your solution requires changing a column type, you could point that out. Because you're right that *I* know `strplit` requires converting to character, but not everyone will know that or debug a solution closely

Comment: @camille  Well, OP's data is blank `""` at the end while creating it and then it got changed to something else.  So, don't know which version you are taking